# No of Services (end points) can Docker/ AWS ECS Container support

Tags: java, docker, amazon-ecs, restful-url, aws-ecr

We have a single docker container (256 CPU units & 1GB RAM) which runs around 40+ services -java based application (controller endpoints). Will there be any problem in running on one container or should we deploy 10 services on 1 container each. So that we have 4 container with 10 services each.
Please suggest me best approach here

Also provide me below information:

1. What is the no. of Services (end points) can Docker/ AWS ECS Container can support ?
2. Is there any limit on exposing the endpoints from the same?
3. How can we increase or decrease it?
4. Is there a way to check the status of no. of supported endpoint?

Comment: "256 CPU units & 1GB RAM" only 4MB/CPU? Seems odd.

Comment: @PeteKirkham..yes its of smallsize (256 CPU units & 996MB) using AWS ECS